Mirth Regex - Replace (
I am trying to write a transformer to replace various different characters but am having difficulties with ( and ). I understand that these are regex characters, but how do I work around wanting to replace instances of them in a string?
for(i=0; i<msg['IN1'].length(); i++){
    msg['IN1'][i]['IN1.4']['IN1.4.1'] = msg['IN1'][i]['IN1.4']['IN1.4.1'].toString().replace(/\/|(|)|%|.|,|'/g, '')
}


escape it : as \( and \)

As Sudhir says, there's a great cheatsheet on this site: https://regexr.com/

@SudhirBastakoti for some reason when i do that it is replacing my entire IN1.4.1 segment with a blank character, not just specifically the ( and ) characters

escape . as well, since it matches ANYTHING - or use /[/()%.,']/g then you don't have to escape anything, or use all those |
